# Unable to install gems in JRuby - (Errno::EACCES) Permission Denied - NUL

Tags: windows, rubygems, jruby

I have a very weird issue and I am not sure what is the cause of that. I am trying to install some gems after installing JRuby. Whatever way (through scoop, manually, .exe file) I have used to install the JRuby I was not able to install any gem and the error I always get is the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - NUL
        org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1255:in `sysopen'
        org/jruby/RubyFile.java:362:in `initialize'
        org/jruby/RubyClass.java:931:in `new'
        org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1174:in `open'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/resolver.rb:176:in `output'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/modules/ui.rb:41:in `after_resolution'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:232:in `end_resolution'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:187:in `resolve'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/resolver.rb:190:in `resolve'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in `resolve'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:333:in `resolve_dependencies'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:201:in `install_gem'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:226:in `block in install_gems'
        org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1988:in `each'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `install_gems'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:167:in `execute'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/command.rb:323:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:185:in `process_args'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:149:in `run'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/bin/jgem:21:in `<main>'
        org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1091:in `load'
        C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/bin/gem:4:in `<main>'
```

my gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.3.25
 - RUBY VERSION: 3.1.0 (2022-11-23 patchlevel 0) [java]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/gems
 - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:\Users\kraptis91/.local/share/gem/jruby/3.1.0
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/bin/jruby.exe
 - GIT EXECUTABLE: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd/git.EXE
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/gems/bin
 - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:\Users\kraptis91/.local/share/gem/specs
 - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/etc
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - universal-java-11
 - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Users/kraptis91/scoop/apps/jruby/current/gems
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--env-shebang"
     - "setup" => "--env-shebang"
     - "pristine" => "--env-shebang"
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
 - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\WINDOWS\system32
     - C:\WINDOWS
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
     - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
     - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
     - C:\Program Files\dotnet\
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\jdk-11.0.15+10\bin
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\gradle-7.2\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
     - C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
     - C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\apache-maven-3.8.2\bin
     - C:\Program Files\nodejs\
     - C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\
     - C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\scoop\apps\jruby\current\bin
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\scoop\apps\jruby\current\gems\bin
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\scoop\shims
     - c:\jruby-9.3.4.0\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\
     - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\AppData\Roaming\npm
     - C:\Users\kraptis91\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
```

**What I have already tried:**

- From what I have read this is maybe a permissions issue therefore I
  tried to open a CMD as an administrator and attempt to install any
  gem this way, but the issue persisted.

Comment: Can you share the command you are invoking to install the gem? Is that error occurring during installation, or when using the gem?

Comment: One thing you could try if you are invoking the install from CMD is to set your GEM_PATH so that it looks in a folder you have permission to, and install using something like:
`java -jar jruby-complete-9.3.9.0.jar -S gem install -i %GEM_PATH% gem-i-like`